# iPhone SDK Question with Audio/Mic

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to do an app, to where when it launches, it will detect audio, and then play it back automatically. NO BUTTONS, nothing to press. Just a picture of something then, it listens for audio, then plays it back. Similar to the Talking Carl app in the App Store. Any ideas/help? Would appreciate it, if i could use the code with IB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work through this example:
http://www.iphoneam.com/blog/index.php?title=using-the-iphone-to-record-audio-a-guide&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1

And then you'll want to put the code for recording and playing back the audio in the `viewDidLoad` method of whichever view is your main view.

One thing you might also want to consider is how long you want it to record before it plays it back?  And also, you'll want to stop recording once the sound starts playing... and also you'll want to start recording again once the sound STOPS playing.... all these things to think about and learn about :)